# Django генерация фильра модели

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Есть фильтр по полям модели:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_text) |
            Q(description__icontains=search_text) |
            Q(name_icontains=search_text)
        )
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы блок

```
Q(title__icontains=search_text) |  
                Q(description__icontains=search_text)|  
                Q(name_icontains=search_text)
```

Генерировался в зависимости от обстоятельств?

Например, в одном случае нужно, чтобы фильтр был такой:

```
Q(description__icontains=search_text) |  
                Q(name_icontains=search_text)
```

В другом такой:

```
Q(title__icontains=search_text) |  
                Q(description__icontains=search_text) |
```

Или даже такой:

```
Q(title__icontains=search_text)
```

Объекты Q я бы мог сгенерировать при помощи словаря, 
Например:

```
search_text = 'somthing text'
fields_name = ['title', 'description', 'name']

 queries = [ Q(**{field+'__icontains': search_text}) for field in fields_name]
```

Но как потом это:

```
 [<Q: (AND: ('title__icontais': 'first'))>,
   <Q: (AND: ('description__icontais': 'first'))>,
   <Q: (AND: ('name__icontais': 'first'))>]
```

Через OR засунуть в filter - не могу никак разобраться. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = Q()
for q in queries:
    query |= q
```

или

```
import operator
query = reduce(operator.or_, queries)
```